# Rotating axis and italic writing

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a plot in R, and I've got some struggles to rotate the xaxis labels, I already tried this command:

labels=lablist, srt=45, pos=1, xpd=TRUE

But it doesn't work as it says it doesn't know labels. Further I don't know how to get the label names in italic.

Has anyone got any suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: do you want to use `ggplot2`? it can be done easily with it...

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. It will help us and especially you to think about the problem you are having. You can simulate the data or chip off a chunk from your dataset (more [hints here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)). Note that all these questions have probably been answered before (R has 145000 questions on SO), for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975797/how-do-you-make-just-the-x-lab-label-italics-and-not-the-y-lab-label-as-well-i

Comment: It's just an easy barplot command

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the entire line of code.  What you have listed will not attract a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

From `?par`:

> ```
> 'srt' The string rotation in degrees.  See the comment about
>      'crt'.  Only supported by 'text'.
> ```

(Not what you want.) Continuing with `'las'` and `'font'`:

> ```
>  'las' numeric in {0,1,2,3}; the style of axis labels.
>       0: always parallel to the axis [_default_],
>       1: always horizontal,
>       2: always perpendicular to the axis,
>       3: always vertical.
>  'font' An integer which specifies which font to use for text.  If
>       possible, device drivers arrange so that 1 corresponds to
>       plain text (the default), 2 to bold face, 3 to italic and 4
>       to bold italic.
> ```

These can give you:

```
barplot(setNames(100 * 1:3, nm=c("abc","def","ghi")), las=2, font=3)
```

[image]

Or perhaps:

```
barplot(setNames(100 * 1:3, nm=c("abc","def","ghi")), las=1, font=3)
```

[image]